# Adding file name in the output file

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I'm using the following code to read data from xml and to write data in stata (.dta) format. For each XML, I want to add file names to the output as well. Can you suggest any changes to my code so that I can have the file name in the output?

```
financials = {"id": ["Header/id/text()"]} # there are few more variables in the list

files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xml")
list = []

for file in files:
    tree = etree.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    # building list per xml
    s_temp = []
    for item in financials:
        s_temp.append(choose_xpath(root, financials[item]))
    list.append(s_temp)

# Building data frame from the collected data from all the xmls
s_df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=list(financials.keys()))
s_df.to_stata("List.dta")
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating a single `List.dta` file. You would have to restructure your code to save the file *inside* your `for` loop. Then instead of `"List.dta"` your filename could be e.g. `file + "List.dta"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) returns a list of filepaths. Using [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=basename#os.path.basename) gets you only the filename. then start your list with it:

```
from os.path import basename

# building list per xml
s_temp = [basename(file)] # filename
```

Comment: I ran the code, and it shows the following error. Any lead on that? ImportError: cannot import name 'basename' from 'os' (C:\Users\mh1417\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py)

Comment: yeah my bad, I forgot that basename is in `os.path`, not `os`. Fixed it.